# Calling _printf in assembly loop, only outputting once

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, x86

I'm learning assembly and I have a very basic loop here

```
segment .data
    msg: db '%d',10,0

segment .text

    global  _asm_main
    extern _printf

_asm_main:

    push DWORD 5 ; Should loop 5 times
    call dump_stack
    add esp,4

    ret

dump_stack:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov ecx, 0

loop_start:
    cmp ecx,[ebp+8] ;compare to the first param of dump_stack, (5)
    jnle loop_end

    push ecx ;push the value of my loop onto the stack
    push DWORD msg ;push the msg (%d) should just print the value of my loop
    call _printf
    add esp, 8 ;clear the stack

    inc ecx ;increment ecx
    jmp loop_start ; go back to my loop start

loop_end:

    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret
```

My output looks something like this

> program.exe
>   0

Just 0, then a newline. I tried to verify the loop was executing by moving my printf to the loop_end part, and it came out with ecx as 6, which is correct. So the loop is executing but printf is not... What am I doing wrong?

(Also, the function is called dump stack because it was initially supposed to dump the details of the stack, but that didn't work because of the same reason here)

And I am compiling with nasm -f win32 program.asm -o program.o
Then I have a cpp file that includes windows.h, and I compiled it with gcc -c include
and finally I linked them with gcc -o program program.o include.o
and I run program.exe

Comment: Why not step through the code in a debugger and see what is actually going on ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that `printf()` modifies `ecx`, it becomes >= `[ebp+8]` and your loop body executes only once. If that's the case, you need to read up on the calling conventions used in your compiler and manually preserve and restore the so-called *volatile registers* (which a called function can freely modify without restoring). Note that there may be several different calling conventions. Use the debugger!

Comment: I checked that by putting my prinf outside of my loop, and ecx was 6 after the loop. Meaning it ran through 6 times.

Comment: If you don't call `printf()` in the loop, nobody modifies `ecx` in the loop, only your `inc ecx`, right? That test alone doesn't test anyhow whether or not `printf()` modifies `ecx`.

Comment: you're right, ecx is 1988740641 after the loop WITH printf in it. I guess the lack of sleep made me not think straight. Alright I should be able to find an alternative. thanks

Comment: Just save and restore `ecx` using the stack. `push ecx` and `pop ecx` in the right places won't hurt.

Comment: pushing/popping `ecx` for each loop iteration is probably not the best idea. This sort of thing will cause unnecessary performance hits if abused. Instead, you should note the call convention of the function. `printf` uses `cdecl` to allow for the variable argument list. Similar to `stdcall`, this call convention mandates `eax`, `ecx` and `edx` to be trashable. Hence you should use another register as the counter (such as `ebx`).

Comment: @MikeKwan: maybe, but not when you're calling printf(), which is a pretty slow function and which shouldn't be called often in places where performance matters.

Comment: I guess I feel this would be the 'proper' way, to work alongside the standard rather than around it.

Comment: @MikeKwan: Standard? What standard?